# How to wait shell command until another one finishes

Tags: vbscript

I got a problem with vbscript.

Hi all,

I have a problem to wait shell.run finished.

If I run 3 shell.run like below, how can I make them wait until prior command finished?

```
srtCmd1 = "msiexec.exe /i c:\a.msi”
srtCmd2 = "msiexec.exe /i c:\b.msi”
srtCmd3 = "c:\c.bat”

objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run srtCmd1, 1, True
objShell.Run srtCmd2, 1, True
objShell.Run srtCmd3, 1, True
```

But they are running almost at the same time.

How can I solve it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

See [Waiting for msiexec.exe to Finish](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/11/15/493236.aspx)

Add "start /wait" (without ") before msiexec.exe

Try:

```
srtCmd1 = "start /wait msiexec.exe /i c:\a.msi”
srtCmd2 = "start /wait msiexec.exe /i c:\b.msi”
```

Comment: But of course the caveat here is that if msiexec fails to install, you won't get an errorlevel set for the batch file to abort... :(